# Font not properly displayed

Tags: html, css

I have a webpage where I'm using the `"font-family: Poppins-Medium;"`
In my PC the font is displayed correctly.
However, in other PCs, only "Times New Roman" font is displayed.
May someone give me a help?

See CSS code:

```
.txt2 {
  font-family: Poppins-Regular;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #999999;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
```

Thanks.

PS: This is the link to the page:
http://ez2main.somee.com/estock/cliadd.asp

Comment: Have you looked at how to add Fonts to your website? Take a look at [this article](https://www.pagecloud.com/blog/how-to-add-custom-fonts-to-any-website) or [this article](https://www.balbooa.com/knowledgebase/32-documentation-faq-joomla/176-how-to-add-custom-font-to-website-through-fontface). This should get you started in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using websafe fonts instead.

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_websafe_fonts.asp

Answer (score 2):

In order to use custom font you should first declare [@font-face](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face). 
It's all written on that link, but let me sum it a little:

step 1: upload font files to the server

step 2: declare font name and use the `src` property to link those files.

step 3: Now custom font will show on every browser since they available on the server.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

When this happens to me it is because I have the font installed on my computer but no on the server. Make sure to set up your custom font with `@font-face` before using it.

`@font-face {
  font-family: 'Poppins-Regular';
  src: url('../font/Poppins-Regular.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('../font/Poppins-Regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('../font/Poppins-Regular.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
       url('../font/Poppins-Regular.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
       url('../font/Poppins-Regular.ttf') format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
}`

Also make sure to add appropriate fall back fonts to make it fail more gracfully.

`font-family: Poppins-Regular, 'second-closest-font', Arial, etc`;

Answer (score 1):

The browser that does not have those fonts installed, tries to load them from the URL http://ez2main.somee.com/fonts/poppins/Poppins-Regular.ttf and that is not a valid URL.

If you provide want to provide those fonts, you should make them available from your server. Otherwise, use standard fonts that every browser would have.